# How to concatenate string variables in a Bash script

Tags: string, bash, variables, cygwin

The following script produces an unexpected output

```
#!/bin/bash
#
MY_DIRECTORY=.
OUTPUT_DIR="$MY_DIRECTORY""/build_test"
echo "MY_DIRECTORY is $MY_DIRECTORY"
echo "OUTPUT_DIR is $OUTPUT_DIR"
```

I expect the following:

```
MY_DIRECTORY is .
OUTPUT_DIR is ./build_test
```

but it actually produces:

```
MY_DIRECTORY is .
/build_testis .
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Note I am running GNU bash version 4.4.12(3)-release in a Cygwin command shell under Windows 10.

Comment: Note that when I type the commands into the shell, they work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with mixed Unix and Windows line endings. You have a carriage return at the end of the `MY_DIRECTORY=` line. The carriage return is causing part of the second output line to be overwritten. I can replicate your output on my Cygwin installation.

If you run the script through `dos2unix` it will work as expected.

To prevent this kind of thing happening again, configure your text editor to save files using Unix line endings.

Answer (score 2):

The script is fine. I tried to run in on my system, and is giving the expected output. I am running Bash version 4.38.48 on Arch.

If you are on Windows, you can try bash on Windows as well, but I do not think that it should affect the output.

Comment: I could have simply commented this thing, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Gave you a couple pluses to help you boost that rep. :)

Comment: Eyy! Thanks a lot!